# Пропадают рабочие столы Active Desktop

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

На рабочих машинах иногда пропадают рабочие столы, рандомно независимо ни от чего, просто черный экран. На большинстве работает, у 3-4 компов стабильно аут

уже пробовал и джпг картинку и бмп, разрешение соответствует разрешению монитора. Включил в групповых политиках ожидание инициализации сети до загрузки рабочего стола, все равно также. Уже не знаю куда копать

У компов процессор от амд, работает на встройке. Может с этим связано?

Windows Server 2019

Comment: Для определения причины необходимо провести диагностику - определить в какой части системы был дефект: сервер, клиент, канал связи. На стороне сервера проверяется просто - проверяется актуальный статус сеанса пользователя, исследуются журналы событий. На стороне клиента - смена RDP-клиента, проверка переподключения, проверка сетевой доступности и пр.

Comment: У нас подобное наблюдалось на встроенных видеокартах от Intel. После того, как поставили недорогие (кажется, Radeon'ы) видеокарты, даже без вентиляторов, проблема исчезла. Правда, Server 2012.